# How can I remove blank fields from a json?

Tags: javascript, json

So I am given a json and I have to clean it up, by removing all the 'blank' fields. The fields that are considered blank are:

- empty arrays or objects,
- strings with whitespace ("" or "   "),
- `null` values.

This is what I have so far:

```
const isBlank = (val) => {
    if(val === null ) {
        return true
    }
    if(typeof val === 'string'){
        return val.trim().length === 0;
    }
    return val.length === 0
};


function clean(jsonInput) {
    Object.keys(jsonInput).forEach( key => {
        if(typeof jsonInput[key] === 'object' && !isEmpty(jsonInput[key])){
            clean(jsonInput[key])
        }else {
            isEmpty(jsonInput[key_field]) && delete jsonInput[key]
        }
    })

}
```

This is the `jsonInput` I am working with:

```
{
    "print": "notBlank",
    "this": "notBlank",
    "example": "notBlank",
    "blank": null,
    "allBlanks": [
        {
            "from": "",
            "blank0": null
        }
    ],
    "att2": {
        "blank1": "",
        "blank2": []
    },
    "att3": {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3",
        "blank3": " "
    }
}
```

This should be the output:

```
{
    "print": "notBlank",
    "this": "notBlank",
    "example": "notBlank",
    "att3": {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3"
    }
}
```

Instead I am getting this:

```
{
    "print": "notBlank",
    "this": "notBlank",
    "example": "notBlank",
    "allBlanks": [{ }],
    "att2": {},
    "att3": {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3",
    }
}
```

It seams like I am unable to remove the objects... Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Any way I can fix it.

Also is there a way to do this so that I don't change the original object and instead I make a duplicate, maybe with `map` or `filter`?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON.  Parse the JSON, then deal with the resulting objects.  Yes, `filter` is generally what you want, and it looks like you want to do this recursively but it isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue here is that `[{}]` was not defined as "empty" because it was an array of length 1 with an object in it. However, because you would like empty objects to be considered empty, and thus arrays with empty objects to be empty, you need to also recurse inside of your `isEmpty` function to cover these angles.

Note the two recursive calls for arrays and objects added to `isEmpty`.

As for as copying goes, the quick dirty way would be to first stringify then parse the json. You can see this towards the bottom of the code with the line

```
var jsonCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
```

There are more complex ways of deep copying as well, please read [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/1026459) for more information there.

```js
const isEmpty = (val) => {
    if(val === null ) {
        return true
    }
    if(typeof val === 'string'){
        return val.trim().length === 0;
    }
    if(val instanceof Array){
        if( val.length === 0 ) return true;
        return val.every( v => 
          isEmpty(v)
        );
    }
    if(val === Object(val)){
        if(Object.keys(val).length == 0) return true;
        return Object.values(val).every( 
            v => isEmpty(v)
        );
    }
    return val.length === 0;
};


function clean(jsonInput) {
    Object.keys(jsonInput).forEach( key =>     {
        if(typeof jsonInput[key] === 'object' && !isEmpty(jsonInput[key])){
            clean(jsonInput[key])
        }else {
            isEmpty(jsonInput[key]) && delete jsonInput[key]
        }
    })
}

var json = {
    "print": "notBlank",
    "this": "notBlank",
    "example": "notBlank",
    "blank": null,
    "allBlanks": [
        {
            "from": "",
            "blank0": null
        }
    ],
    "att2": {
        "blank1": "",
        "blank2": []
    },
    "att3": {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3",
        "blank3": " "
    }
};
var jsonCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
clean(jsonCopy);
console.log(jsonCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some features like this already exist in the **lodash**

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#omitBy

> Avoid using **delete** in javascript, its slow and not a good pratice

Example:

```
var _ = require("lodash")

var oldObj = {a:1, b:2, c:null, d:"aa"}

var newObj = _.omitBy(oldObj, (value, key) => 
                              _.isNull(value) || 
                              (_.isString(value) && _.isEmpty(value)) ||
                              (_.isArray(value) && _.isEmpty(value))  );
console.log("Final", newObj) //Final { a: 1, b: 2, d: 'aa' }
```

> **isEmpty** return true if value is a number https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEmpty

Edit:

> The keyword **delete** throws an exception in strict mode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: I changed to omitBy function, cloneDeepWith didnt works for me.